# SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Can't assign requested address, errno = 49)

Tags: flutter

Today when I start the flutter(v3.0.5) app debugging in the macOS 12.5, the android studio console shows error log like this:

```
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196mDioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Can't assign requested address, errno = 49), address = api.example.top, port = 443<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196m#0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196m#1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196m<asynchronous suspension><…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196m#2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:586:9)<…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196m<asynchronous suspension><…>
flutter: \^[[38;5;196m│ \^[[0m\^[[39m\^[[48;5;196m<…>
```

I am sure the `api.example.top` works fine, why could not connect to the api in the iOS emulator? what should I do to fixed this problem? this is the android studio version info:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8815526, built on July 10, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.5.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2280M
Cores: 10
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Dart (212.5744), com.thoughtworks.gauge (212.4746.52), org.moe.community (1.4.10), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46), io.flutter (69.0.2)
```

when I am using the `netstat -a` command in terminal, the part of the output like this:

```
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.51377   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.50273   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.62423   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.56977   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.56547   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.56367   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.55088   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.52435   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.64959   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
tcp4       0      0  xiaoqiangs-mbp.62059   ec2-54-78-39-141.https ESTABLISHED
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the url with https

```dart
Uri _uri = Uri.parse("https://api.example.top");
```